# R: apt-get install r-cran-foo vs. install.packages("foo")

Tags: r, ubuntu, debian, cran

When installing R packages (say `mcmcpack` in this example) under Ubuntu I have the choice between the following two methods of installation:

```
# Let the distribution's packaging system take care of installation/upgrades
apt-get install r-cran-mcmcpack

# Let R take care of installation/upgrades
install.packages("mcmcpack")
```

Questions:

- Is any of the two ways of installing R packages considered "best practice"?
- Assume that I first `install.packages("mcmcpack")` and later on `apt-get install r-cran-mcmcpack` - should I expect trouble?
- Assume that I first `apt-get install r-cran-mcmcpack` and later on `install.packages("mcmcpack")` - should I expect trouble?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Update** (some thirteens years later): *It is now as easy as it seems* if you use for example the wonderful and powerful [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) system I set up last year, and which now provides over 20k binary .deb packages for each of twi Ubuntu LTS releases (currently: 20.04 and 22.04), and is also accessible via `install.packages()` thanks top `bspm`. Follow the link to [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) for more.

---

It's not as easy as it seems.

- `apt-get update` is good if and when

  - packages exist -- but there are only around 150 or so `r-cran-*` packages out of a pool of 2100+ packages on CRAN, so rather sparse coverage
  - packages are maintained, bug free and current
  - you are happy enough with the bi-annual releases by Ubuntu
- `install.packages()` and later `update.packages()` is good if and when

  - you know what it takes to have built-time dependencies (besides `r-base-dev`) installed
  - you don't mind running `update.packages()` by hand as well as the `apt-get` updates.

On my Ubuntu machine at work, I go with the second solution.  But because the first one is better *if you have enough coverage*, we have built [**cran2deb**](http://debian.cran.r-project.org/) which provides 2050+ binary deb packages for amd64 and i386 --- but only for Debian testing.  That is what I use at home.

As for last question of whether you 'should you expect trouble':  No, because `R_LIBS_SITE` is set in `/etc/R/Renvironment` to be

```
# edd Apr 2003  Allow local install in /usr/local, also add a directory for
#               Debian packaged CRAN packages, and finally the default dir 
# edd Jul 2007  Now use R_LIBS_SITE, not R_LIBS
R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:\
/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library'}
```

which means that *your* packages go into `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` whereas those managed by `apt` go into `/usr/lib/R/site-library` and (in the case of base packages) `/usr/lib/R/library`.

Hope that clarifies matters.  The r-sig-debian mailing list is a more informed place for questions like this.

Comment: Dirk, I hate to make this a stand alone question... Why are some packages (e.g. RODBC) only able to be installed using the apt-get install method?

Comment: Where? How? When? What platform? Feel free to email r-sig-debian, that;s what we have it for (SO fanboy-ism notwithstanding).

Comment: Did you 'simply' miss the odbc development package etc?  Well, that would be _why_ we started to provide these. RODBC was actually one of the first I packaged...

Comment: See also https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html for repositories to install recent R and R packages.

Answer (score 5):

- I'd consider using `apt-get` best practice since you will get automatic updates through the standard system tools.
- Having 2 versions installed might get you into confusing situations: depending on your R setup you could load another package version then you expect -- your private (maybe outdated) one should in general be loaded first.
- See above.

Comment: or see Dirk's answer for the whole story