# R Package Need compilation

Tags: r, r-package

When I install.packages(), sometimes I got this message: "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)". Can someone give me a brief explanation?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/9644699/3093387 help you? If not, could you please share some more details about the sort of information you'd like to know about package compilation?

Comment: Thanks! Yes it helps. For my issue is the root privilege issue.